# Calling Camera.WorldToViewportPoint() from a job

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Anyone have any clue of the implementation / source code for Camera.WorldToViewportPoint()?  It's natively implemented so no source.  I need to use it off the main thread in a Unity pure ECS job, but I get an error that it can't be called off the main thread.

Comment: Almost everything in the Unity API needs to be called on the main thread since Unity isn't theadsafe ... special here is that it toally depends on the cameras position at the point of execution so you can't do it completely independent from the main thread where the camera position is handled.

Comment: Getting the position of the camera may need to be done on the main thread, but I'm wanting to then pass that info into a job and do transforms in there that wouldn't need to be on the UI thread.

Comment: You could try use a shared variable, set it from the main thread and read it from the job ... however there will probably be no warranty that you will get the correct frame's value ... Could you add your code/setup?